# GRASS GIS not starting

Tags: grass-gis

I have a problem with GRASS GIS 6.4.3.

I installed QGIS 2.4 with GRASS GIS 6.4.3 GUI on Windows 7 64 bit - admin user. When I click on GRASS GIS icon the program not starting (without error messages). I see the first map (loading gui) but the software not starting.

I tried uninstall and reinstall software but the problem remain.

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my english.

Best regard

PS If I call GRASS from cmd (windows) I read error like in image file

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

The LOCATION_NAME variable is not set. To start a project with GRASS, you need to set a "fully qualified initial mapset directory" which is defined by a "GISDBASE/LOCATION_NAME/MAPSET" path.

Have you tried to launch GRASS from the start menu instead of the cmd window? After this first launch, you will be asked to set the variables.

Comment: Bonsoir Pierre. Yes, I tried to launch GRASS from the start menu. After the launch from start (or icon Grass 6.4.3 GUI) menu I see the old map image for only few seconds but grass not starting (like in this video http://ge.tt/5YD5Ftz1/v/0?c). Can I modify manually the location_name from command line?

Comment: You are starting grass64 from the QGIS folder. Is GRASS installed elsewhere? Maybe can you try to create a new LOCATION from QGIS as described in this short tutorial : http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/grass/grass_setup.html

Comment: Hello. I solved the problem by installing grass 7 but I will try to follow your advice for grass 6. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since GRASS GIS 6.4.3 should ideally start, maybe there is junk in the session configuration file (%APPDATA%\GRASS6\grassrc6 for GRASS 6 or %APPDATA%\GRASS7\rc for GRASS 7) where %APPDATA% is usually C:\Users\\AppData. To test, rename it and a new one will be created next time you run GRASS GIS. Note that %APPDATA% is a hidden folder.

(cited from http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WinGRASS_errors#The_startup_fails_with_a_GISDBASE_not_defined_error)

Comment: Hello. I renamed the file, but the problem remained. I solved the problem by installing grass 7 3-1 beta (only for grass 7, grass 6 not starting). Thank at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with GRASS GIS 7.2.0.
The program finished wrongly and now,  when I do click on GRASS GIS icon the program doesn't start. 
The error message is "variable location_name is not defined"
I have attented uninstall this version and reinstall 7.2.2 (new release) but the problem remains.
Thanks for your help.