# v.clean is stuck at 0%

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, v.clean

So I have a layer with thousands of gaps and overlaps that I want to tidy up, but when I go to run `v.clean` in order to do so, it just sits there at 0%. I have no warnings or errors in the system, and QGIS itself is not responding. Normally when this happens, I just leave it alone and it sorts itself out. However it's been over two hours now and nothing has changed.

I'm running the latest version of QGIS and GRASS, and there's plenty of unused RAM and disk space the program could be using, but it's not. What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: What if you try running `v.clean` on a small extract of your *big data*, are you still getting `0%`? Are you aware of the [GRASS GIS Python library](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/libpython/), so maybe it can be useful for a big data set without running commands via the QGIS's UI. Perhaps you will find something relevant here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115443/grass-gis-not-starting

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure you specify a dedicated output location, instead of leaving the output locations blank (ie: Don't use Create Temporary Layer) - Ive found sometimes I get better performance and remove any access restrictions that may exist in the temporary area.

Also as above with Taras' answer, do a small sample to begin with.

Also im not sure what your input formats are. I know sometimes service based inputs (like a WFS) can be problematic, if there is a 'get' size limit imposed on the service layer. Sometimes it might be good to just save a local copy of the data to help eliminate performance/access issues.

Comment: I've tried both methods suggested and nothing has changed. I'm not sure what's holding it up. I took this screenshot to see if maybe the answer lies there somewhere: https://i.imgur.com/RFl1xsa.png